# canopen chain node exit with error code -11 at start

Tags: ros, ros-control, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to connect to an link[http://www.a-m-c.com/download/datasheet/dzcante-060l080.pdf "AMC DZCante 60L080"].

I know that I am connecting to the can bus as i can run socketcam_dump and see the drive's power on message. When I run the canopen_chain_node's chain the launch with the following yaml file:

```
bus:
      device: can0
     master_allocator: canopen::SimpleMaster::Allocator
sync:
     interval_ms: 5 
     overflow: 0
defaults:
     publish: ["1001sub0"]
nodes:
     node1: #Torso
     id: 42 
     name: Torso
     eds_file: '/robots/q1/axis1.eds'
```

I get the following the in logs:

```
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2016-07-15 22:06:38,132: [canopen_chain-1] process has died [pid 3572, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/canopen_chain_node/canopen_chain_node __name:=canopen_chain __log:=/home/ocu/.ros/log/1371681c-4ac4-11e6-956c-001c23b398d6/canopen_chain-1.log].
```

The canopen_chain-1.log file does not exist so I am at loss on what to do next. I just want to establish basic communication with my drive. My overall goal is to connect my drive with ros control.

My help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239635/canopen-chain-node-exit-with-error-code--11-at-start/) by [qnetjoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27506/qnetjoe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2016-07-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2016-09-29**:
Have you try with a more basic config file? without the nodes and defaults field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The released version is outdated, better try the source version.
Please check the indention of your config, it looks a little bit shifted.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2016-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2